# Clueless on how to use fsockopen()

Tags: php, ftp

I am very new to php, and i am trying to connect to ftp and post a form, which has a few text fields, and 3 image upload, the images will be uploaded to the server. I am using godaddy, and they dont allow ftp_connect, only fsocketopen(),and only available on ports 80 (http) and 443(https). Can i have some advice on how to approach this(fsockopen)?

I researched and below is what i got, i assume the first part is server, second part is the port so i assume is 80(as godaddy said only that 2 ports are available), but what are the last 3? The $error_number,$error_string, and the last part?

Thanks for your time. Sorry that if the question is a newbie question. I researched for a while, i still can't fix it.

```
fsockopen('abc.com', '80', $error_number, $error_string, 30)

<?php
$ftp_user_name='name';
$ftp_user_pass='pass';
$connection = 'server';
$errno='';
$connect= fsockopen("abc.info", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30) or die ("Cannot connect to host");

$login = ftp_login($connect, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);


if (!$connect) 
{die ("FTP connection has encountered an error!");}


 //exit;


if (!$login)
{die ("But failed at login Attempted to connect to $connection for user $ftp_user_name....");}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of sounding conceited, [RTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) please.

From the [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/function.fsockopen):

> `errno`
>  If provided, holds the system level error number that
> occurred in the system-level connect() call. If the value returned in
> errno is 0 and the function returned FALSE, it is an indication that
> the error occurred before the connect() call. This is most likely due
> to a problem initializing the socket.
>
> `errstr`
>  The error message as a string.
>
> `timeout`
>  The connection timeout, in seconds.

Comment: Haha no its ok, i did read that manual, i just have no clue what it is trying to say lol but i will give that a try to see if its alright, cos i am pretty retarded at following instructions haha

Comment: `errno` and `errstr` are simply identifiers for what the function returns if the connection is unsuccessful. `timeout` is the number of seconds to wait for a connection before failing.

Comment: I tried it but i have ftp_login(): supplied resource is not a valid FTP Buffer resource..... i will give it another go after i have a sleep, been on this for hours

Comment: That's another question. If you're having problems, you should start another question on SO, and post the relevant code. In the meantime, you might like to accept this answer, since it does answer your initial question.